# javascript function called with an onclick attribute on button

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I don't understand why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qeCE5/) is not working.
I'm sticking to the reference on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).
Here the code :

HTML:

```
<button onclick="click()">Test</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function click() {
    alert("Hello !");
}
```

Comment: W3Schools is a rubbish tutorial site, it is not at all affiliated with the W3C.

Comment: I hate who whenever see a w3school link paste the common sentence: "w3school ...." without continuing reading the answer!

Comment: @Ahmad — It's a question, not an answer, and I read all of it. (And now I've edited the question to remove the problematic misattribution of the content)

Comment: @Quentin, so where is the problem with W3Schools here ?

Comment: @Ahmad — They aren't the W3C as the question claimed.

Comment: you said this was a rubbish tutorial, can you link something better?

Comment: MDN is usually a better bet (or using the actual specs from the W3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have configured JSFiddle to wrap the JavaScript in a function and call it `onload`. This stops your function being a global so it isn't in scope for your intrinsic event handler attribute.

Additionally, after you fix that, the weird scoping rules for intrinsic event attributes (I have no idea where these are documented) means that `click` is resolved as the button's `click` property before the scope is searched far enough to find the global `click` function.

The quick and dirty solution is:

- Rename the function to something that doesn't clash with existing property names
- Pick a *no wrap* option from the menu on the left of JSFiddle

---

The proper solution is to attach your event handlers with JavaScript. This isn't the 1990s and we should avoid using the techniques of that era that fail to separate concerns. Keep your JS in one place and your HTML in another.

```
<button>Test</button> 

<script>
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', click);
function click(evt) {
    alert("Hello !");
}
</script>
```

Comment: `no wrap` first time i saw this option .. great

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't work because there's already a `click` native method and shadowing it prevents the normal click event handling. Give it another name and it will work.

A way to see that is to define your button as

```
<button onclick="console.log(click)">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you cann't give a function name as `click`. Change your function name & it should work.

Answer (score 1):

`click` seems to be reserved.
Try renaming the method: http://jsfiddle.net/qeCE5/1/

```
function clickMe() {
    alert("Hello !");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the function name. 'click' might be a reserved keyword, so it wont recognize when you call it. rename it to other names eg. 'democlick()'. also don't forget to save your code with '.html. extension. please tell me if any issue exists. thanks.